# How to use "get_or_create()" in Django?

Tags: python, django, function, object, django-models

I'm trying to use `get_or_create()` for some fields in my forms, but I'm getting a 500 error when I try to do so.

One of the lines looks like this:

```py
customer.source = Source.objects.get_or_create(name="Website")
```

The error I get for the above code is:

> Cannot assign "(<Source: Website>, False)": "Customer.source" must be a "Source" instance.

Answer (score 517, accepted):

From the documentation [get_or_create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create):

```
# get_or_create() a person with similar first names.

p, created = Person.objects.get_or_create(
    first_name='John',
    last_name='Lennon',
    defaults={'birthday': date(1940, 10, 9)},
)

# get_or_create() didn't have to create an object.
>>> created
False
```

**Explanation:** 
Fields to be evaluated for similarity, have to be mentioned outside `defaults`. Rest of the fields have to be included in `defaults`. In case CREATE event occurs, all the fields are taken into consideration.

It looks like you need to be returning into a tuple, instead of a single variable, do like this:

```
customer.source,created = Source.objects.get_or_create(name="Website")
```

Comment: FYI created is a boolean. True if created, False if it is fetched

Comment: A additional `save()` is redundant?

Comment: @zypro It's like `create()`, create object and save it all in one step and doesn't need any `save()`

Comment: NOTE: As of Django 3.2, any statement passed in `defaults` are evaluated even if a new object is not created. I ended up writing try catch statement whenever `create` needs a complex statement to execute.

Comment: What does the p in "p, created = Person..." stand for? What's the purpose?

Comment: @alkadelik, the p should be the object that has been fetched or newly created via the ORM

Answer (score 42):

`get_or_create` returns a tuple.

```
customer.source, created = Source.objects.get_or_create(name="Website")
```

Comment: Or, if you don't care about the boolean flag: `customer.source = Source.objects.get_or_create(name="Website")[0]`

Comment: @mipadi I'd prefer `customer.source, _ = Source.objects.get_or_create(name="Website")`, as it makes the fact that a tuple was returned more obvious, helping avoid future bugs.

Answer (score 33):

[`get_or_create()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create) returns a tuple:

```
customer.source, created  = Source.objects.get_or_create(name="Website")
```

- `created` **→** has a boolean value, is created or not.
- `customer.source` **→** has an object of `get_or_create()` method.

Answer (score 22):

Following @Tobu answer and @mipadi comment, in a more pythonic way, if not interested in the created flag, I would use:

```
customer.source, _ = Source.objects.get_or_create(name="Website")
```

Answer (score 7):

The issue you are encountering is a documented feature of `get_or_create`.

When using keyword arguments other than "defaults" the return value of `get_or_create` is an instance.  That's why it is showing you the parens in the return value.

you could use `customer.source = Source.objects.get_or_create(name="Website")[0]` to get the correct value.

Here is a link for the documentation: 
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create-kwargs

Answer (score 3):

[get_or_create()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create) returns the tuple which contains 2 values and the 1st value is **an object** and the 2nd value is the boolean value which indicates that a new object is created or not as shown below:

```
 # 1st   # 2nd
(object, boolean)
```

So, if you want both **an object** and **a boolean value**, put one more variable `created` after `customer.source` as shown below:

```py
                 # Here
customer.source, created = Source.objects.get_or_create(name="Website")
# object         # boolean
```

And, if you want only **an object** without a boolean value, put `[0]` just after `get_or_create()` as shown below:

```py
                                                       # Here ↓↓↓
customer.source = Source.objects.get_or_create(name="Website")[0]
# object
```

And, if you want only **a boolean value** without an object put `[1]` just after `get_or_create()` as shown below:

```py
                                               # Here ↓↓↓
created = Source.objects.get_or_create(name="Website")[1]
# boolean
```

Answer (score 1):

get_or_create method would actually return a tuple.

The trick with the get_or_create method is that it actually returns a tuple of (object, created). The first element is an instance of the model you are trying to retrieve and the second is a boolean flag to tell if the instance was created or not. True means the instance was created by the get_or_create method and False means it was retrieved from the database

So you can do something like to get the source instance

````
 ```   customer.source = Source.objects.get_or_create(name="Website")[0]
 ```
````

Answer (score 0):

Important warning.

you should take care of the following before using the get_or_create , https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/.
....
Warning

This method is atomic assuming that the database enforces uniqueness of the keyword arguments (see unique or unique_together). If the fields used in the keyword arguments do not have a uniqueness constraint, concurrent calls to this method may result in multiple rows with the same parameters being inserted.