# Setting default value for Foreign Key attribute in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, foreign-keys, default

What is the best way to set a default value for a foreign key field in a model? Suppose I have two models, `Student` and `Exam` with student having `exam_taken` as foreign key. How would I ideally set a default value for it? Here's a log of my effort

```py
class Student(models.Model):
   ....
   .....
   exam_taken = models.ForeignKey("Exam", default=1)
```

Works, but have a hunch there's a better way.

```py
def get_exam():
    return Exam.objects.get(id=1)
    
class Student(models.Model):
    ....
    .....
    exam_taken = models.ForeignKey("Exam", default=get_exam)
```

But this fails with tables does not exist error while syncing.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: how about: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/937954/how-do-you-specify-a-default-for-a-django-foreignkey-model-or-adminmodel-field

Comment: @NitzanTomer It for a AdminModelField. Had seen it previously.

Comment: @TomIngram: `default=get_exam()` will call `get_exam` immediately and store the value permanently, whereas `default=get_exam` stores the method which would later be called each time the `default` attribute is used, to get the value at that moment. It's often used with datetime, i.e. `default=datetime.now`, *not* `default=datetime.now()`.

Comment: @TomIngram: I'm not debating the merits of one approach over another. My point was only that it is valid, and the author seems to want it that way.

Comment: @ChrisPratt "This can be a value or a callable object. If callable it will be called every time a new object is created." so this means `default=get_exam()` and `default=get_exam` effectively is the same, unless you can re-call default?

Comment: @TomIngram: The difference is that when you add the parenthesis, it's no longer a "callable"; it's a static value, no different that just putting an integer there.

Comment: @ChrisPratt hello I understand the difference etc, what I guess I'm struggling with is working out why. Giving it a bit of thought I'm thinking that as external states change perhaps the required default value will also and you would need to re-evaluate this value using the callback you passed, maybe I'm also over emphasising or misinterpreting `default` as to me it reads as something that should be relatively static, thanks it's been interesting and thought provoking for me at least :)

Answer (score 32):

As already implied in @gareth's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9312738), hard-coding a default `id` value might not always be the best idea:

If the `id` value does not exist in the database, you're in trouble. Even if that specific `id` value does exist, the corresponding object may change. In any case, when using a hard-coded `id` value, you'd have to resort to things like data-migrations or manual editing of existing database content.

To prevent that, you could use [get_or_create()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create) in combination with a `unique` field (other than `id`).

Here's one way to do it:

```py
from django.db import models

 
class Exam(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    
    @classmethod
    def get_default_pk(cls):
        exam, created = cls.objects.get_or_create(
            title='default exam', 
            defaults=dict(description='this is not an exam'),
        )
        return exam.pk
    
    
class Student(models.Model):
    exam_taken = models.ForeignKey(
        to=Exam, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=Exam.get_default_pk
    )
```

Here an `Exam.title` field is used to get a unique object, and an `Exam.description` field illustrates how we can use the `defaults` argument (for `get_or_create`) to fully specify the default `Exam` object.

Note that we return a `pk`, as suggested by the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#default):

> For fields like `ForeignKey` that map to model instances, defaults should be the value of the field they reference (`pk` unless `to_field` is set) instead of model instances.

Also note that `default` callables are evaluated in `Model.__init__()` ([source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.0.x/django/db/models/base.py#L474)). So, if your default value depends on another field of the same model, or on the request context, or on the state of the client-side form, you should probably look [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1969081).

Comment: It doesn't work if U have not any migrations yet for me. I use field role for User, where I use `get_default_user_role` callback as default parameter like in your example. So if I have no migrations I got `no such table: users_role` on `python manage.py makemigration`. But if I comment `role field` in *User* model and `run makemigrations` - it is no problems. After what I uncomment `role field` and `run migrations` again with no problems. Maybe U can halp me with that?

Comment: @parfeniukink: I would be happy to help, but it is a bit difficult to tell what is going wrong without seeing your actual code. Perhaps you could create a new Question with some more details?

Comment: Oh, Thanks a lot, but I've finished this task )))

Comment: I like the approach but get_or_create returns a tuple object and tuple have no pk ! exam[0] would have pk !

Comment: @Elcast If you look closely, the [tuple is unpacked](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) in the example: `exam, created = cls.objects.get_or_create(...)`, so the first item is assigned to `exam`, the second item is assigned to `created`. Exactly like the [example in the Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create).

Comment: You're correct, I have not followed (copy paste) your code 100% so I got different results, adding created make sense now. Thanks for share and the explanation..

Comment: @djvg I Had one doubt about your answer. (This might be a silly question). Generally, we use parenthesis when calling a function in Python. But there isn't any parenthesis in (default=Exam.get_default_pk). Can you please explain why this is the case?

Comment: @DigvijayNikam `Exam.get_default_pk` (*without* parentheses) is a "reference" to the method itself: it does not *call* the method. Later, if you instantiate a `Student()` object, without specifying a value for the `exam_taken` field, it will call `Exam.get_default_pk()` (*with* parentheses) to determine the actual `default` value, at that time. Also see the [example in the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#default).

Answer (score 25):

I would modify @vault's answer above slightly (this may be a new feature). It is definitely desirable to refer to the field by a natural name. However instead of overriding the `Manager` I would simply use the `to_field` param of `ForeignKey`:

```
class Country(models.Model):
    sigla   = models.CharField(max_length=5, unique=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % self.sigla

class City(models.Model):
    nome   = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=True)
    nation = models.ForeignKey(Country, to_field='sigla', default='IT')
```

Answer (score 14):

I use natural keys to adopt a more natural approach:

`<app>/models.py`

```
from django.db import models

class CountryManager(models.Manager):
    """Enable fixtures using self.sigla instead of `id`"""

    def get_by_natural_key(self, sigla):
        return self.get(sigla=sigla)

class Country(models.Model):
    objects = CountryManager()
    sigla   = models.CharField(max_length=5, unique=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % self.sigla

class City(models.Model):
    nome   = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=True)
    nation = models.ForeignKey(Country, default='IT')
```

Comment: I tried this in Django 1.6 but I get the error, "Invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'IT'. (My string is different, but you get the idea.)

Comment: This worked fine, though, and seems more Pythonic: `default=lambda: Country.objects.filter(sigla='IT').first()`

Comment: Strange, I remember to have tested this with django 1.6. Googling I found it's a tuple problem, try: `def get_by_natural_key(self, sigla): return (self.get(sigla=sigla),)` or also with `default=('IT',)`. I'm just guessing ;)

Comment: "Natural" is a problematic concept here.  What you seem to be saying is that you're forcing the user to choose a five-character ID for each item, but that is not inherently more natural than a serial number.

Answer (score 11):

The issue with most of these approaches are that they use **HARD CODED** values or lambda methods inside the Model which are not supported anymore since Django Version 1.7.

In my opinion, the best approach here is to use a [sentinel](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.SET) method which can also be used for the `on_delete` argument.

So, in your case, I would do

```py
# Create or retrieve a placeholder
def get_sentinel_exam():
    return Exam.objects.get_or_create(name="deleted",grade="N/A")[0]

# Create an additional method to return only the id - default expects an id and not a Model object
def get_sentinel_exam_id():
    return get_sentinel_exam().id

class Exam(models.Model):
    ....
    # Making some madeup values
    name=models.CharField(max_length=200) # "English", "Chemistry",...
    year=models.CharField(max_length=200) # "2012", "2022",...

class Student(models.Model):
    ....
    .....
    exam_taken = models.ForeignKey("Exam",    
                       on_delete=models.SET(get_sentinel_exam),
                       default=get_sentinel_exam_id
                 )
```

Now, when you just added the `exam_taken` field uses a guaranteed existing value while also, when deleting the exam, the Student themself are not deleted and have a foreign key to a `deleted` value.

Comment: This worked perfectly — I had a website admin where there were overall site settings, and one of them was the default language. I don't know in advance which languages will be available, and this enabled me to provide a default of "undefined".

Comment: What about performance? It doesn't execute a database hit for every call?

Comment: @realnot It's been some time that I used it, so this may be opinionated. Calling the `get_sentinel_exam` method executes a query whenever a referential action is invoked (`ON DELETE` in this case). So to answer your question - unless you don't delete a row, a second query is not performed

Comment: @Advena Had one doubt in your answer. (This might be a silly question). Generally, we use parenthesis when calling a function in Python. But there isn't any parenthesis in (default=get_sentinel_exam_id). Can you please explain why this is the case?

Comment: @DigvijayNikam, been some time i worked in Python, but I would believe that this is a method reference. With parenthesis, you're asking for it to execute immediately, except when the model is actually used. The fallback exam id could change for some reason. (Somebody correct me if I'm mistaken)

Answer (score 9):

In my case, I wanted to set the default to any *existing* instance of the related model.  Because it's possible that the `Exam` with id `1` has been deleted, I've done the following:

```
class Student(models.Model):
    exam_taken = models.ForeignKey("Exam", blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            self.exam_taken
        except:
            self.exam_taken = Exam.objects.first()
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

If `exam_taken` doesn't exist, `django.db.models.fields.related_descriptors.RelatedObjectDoesNotExist` will be raised when a attempting to access it.

Answer (score 4):

You could use this pattern:

```
class Other(models.Model):
    DEFAULT_PK=1
    name=models.CharField(max_length=1024)

class FooModel(models.Model):
    other=models.ForeignKey(Other, default=Other.DEFAULT_PK)
```

Of course you need to be sure that there is a row in the table of `Other`. You should use a datamigration to be sure it exists.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [get_or_create()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create) in `get_exam()` and [on_delete](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete) for [models.ForeignKey()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey) as shown below. *Don't forget to put `.id` just after `get_or_create(id=1)[0]` because [default](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#default)  in `models.ForeignKey()` needs `id` of an `Exam` object otherwise there is an error and you can see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1941212/how-to-use-get-or-create-in-django/76225010#76225010) explaining about `get_or_create()`:

```py
def get_exam():        # Here                # ↓ Don't forget
    return Exam.objects.get_or_create(id=1)[0].id

class Student(models.Model):
    # ...
    exam_taken = models.ForeignKey(
        "Exam", 
        default=get_exam, 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE # Here
    )
```

And, you can put `get_exam()` in `Student` class as shown below:

```py
class Student(models.Model):
    # ...
    def get_exam(): # Here
        return Exam.objects.get_or_create(id=1)[0].id

    exam_taken = models.ForeignKey(
        "Exam", 
        default=get_exam, 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
```

I recommend to use `@classmethod` for `get_exam()` in `Student` class as shown below so that other classes can also use `get_exam()` by class name. *`@classmethod` can do more things than `@staticmethod` according to [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136097/difference-between-staticmethod-and-classmethod?page=1&tab=trending#answer-74470227):

```py
class Student(models.Model):
    # ...
    @classmethod # Here
    def get_exam(cls):
        return Exam.objects.get_or_create(id=1)[0].id

    exam_taken = models.ForeignKey(
        "Exam", 
        default=get_exam, 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
```

And instead of `get_exam`, you can assign `get_exam()` to `default` as shown below:

```py
def get_exam():
    return Exam.objects.get_or_create(id=1)[0].id

class Student(models.Model):
    # ...
    exam_taken = models.ForeignKey(
        "Exam", # ↓ Here ↓
        default=get_exam(),
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
```

```py
class Student(models.Model):
    # ...
    def get_exam():
        return Exam.objects.get_or_create(id=1)[0].id

    exam_taken = models.ForeignKey(
        "Exam", # ↓ Here ↓
        default=get_exam(), 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking for the solution in **Django Admin**, then I found this:

```py
class YourAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin)

    def get_changeform_initial_data(self, request):
        return {'owner': request.user}
```

this also allows me to use the current user.

[see django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/_modules/django/contrib/admin/options/#ModelAdmin.get_changeform_initial_data)

Answer (score 0):

the **best** way I know is to use lambdas

```
class TblSearchCase(models.Model):
    weights = models.ForeignKey('TblSearchWeights', models.DO_NOTHING, default=lambda: TblSearchWeights.objects.get(weight_name='value_you_want'))
```

so you can specify the default row..

```
default=lambda: TblSearchWeights.objects.get(weight_name='value_you_want')
```

Comment: Error: Cannot serialize function 'lambda'

Comment: that was Django 2, I'm not sure about 3 or 4.

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding something on top of @djvg [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62697872/22687500) and providing some illustration to @Super Kai [one's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76225149/22687500) concerning the class method way of solving this problem:

Using a class method is also useful in this case, and probably in a lot of other cases, because you may have to add other ForeignKey relationships to your model later on like so:

```
from django.db import models


class Exam(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    @classmethod
    def get_default_pk(cls):
        exam, created = cls.objects.get_or_create(
            title='default exam', 
            defaults=dict(description='this is not an exam'),
        )
        return exam.pk


class Student(models.Model):
    exam_taken = models.ForeignKey(
        to=Exam, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=Exam.get_default_pk
    )

# NEW
class Teacher(models.Model):
        exam_given = models.ForeignKey(
            to=Exam, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=Exam.get_default_pk
        )
```

In my case, I came here to figure out how to provide a default image to a Photo model whom I wanted to be used by several other models that would also use that default image like so:

```
class Photo(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos',
        default="default_photo_folder/default_image")

    @classmethod
    def get_or_create_default_photo_pk(cls):
        obj, created_bool = cls.objects.get_or_create(
            title='default photo', # ↓ title value will be automatically included in defaults ↓
            defaults=dict(image="default_photo_folder/default_image"),
            )
    return obj.pk

------------------------------------------------------------------
# From photoapp.models import Photo

class Event(models.Model):
    photo = models.ForeignKey(Photo,
                        on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT,
                        related_name='event_photos',
                        default=Photo.get_or_create_default_photo_pk)

class Place(models.Model):
    photo = models.ForeignKey(Photo,
                        on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT,
                        related_name='place_photos',
                        default=Photo.get_or_create_default_photo_pk)
```

Please note that in this example I already have a default photo in my media/default_photo folder. I also used models.SET_DEFAULT to set my default photo as the object's photo when its original photo would be deleted. As stated in the doc, I also used a unique field lookup in my get_or_create() method to avoid [extra headache](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/4.2/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create) .