# how to add multiple customer address from django admin

Tags: python, django-models, django-admin

Okay, newbie here. So I am working on a project where the requirement is : I have to make a Customer model ,where admin/staff can add the customer's details.
Now the problem is admin/staff can add multiple address against a customer.I can't find any proper idea ,how would I make it.
But still I made a plan ..

[image]

and I added some code.

## customer-models.py

> 

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import JSONField
from decimal import Decimal
from django.db import models
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

# Create your models here.
class customer(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    profile_image = models.FileField()
    phone_number = models.BigIntegerField()

    def profile(self):
        if self.profile_image!="":
            return mark_safe('<img src="/media/%s" width="150" height="150" />' % (self.profile_image))
        else:
            return "";
    profile.short_description = 'Image'
    # profile.allow_tags = True
```

## Customer_address-models.py

> 

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from customer.models import customer
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Address(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(customer,default=0)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    city =models.CharField(max_length=150)
    pin_code =  models.BigIntegerField()

    # def customer_address(self):
    #   return fields = ["country","state","city","pin_code"]
```

## customer - admin.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from .models import customer
from customer_address.models import Address
from django.contrib import admin

# Register your models here.
class CustomerAddressInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Address

class CustomerAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ["first_name","last_name","phone_number","profile"]
    list_select_related = True
    inlines = [
        CustomerAddressInline,
    ]

    search_fields = ["first_name","last_name","phone_number"]
    fields = ( "first_name","last_name","phone_number",'profile',"profile_image","customer_address" )
    readonly_fields = ('profile',)
    class Meta:
        model = customer

admin.site.register(customer,CustomerAdmin)
```

cant figure it out,how I  show/edit/instert all fields as address in customer module from admin.A little help would be much appreciated 
Thank you 
P.S : I am using django-1.11.10

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things wrong here.

Model names are title cased `Customer` instead of `customer`.

Not sure why your using two apps for the `customer` and `customer_address`

The image field `profile_image` should use [`ImageField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#imagefield) as this has validation logic for images.

An will suggest not having methods on the model that return markup for image it should be in the template.

Something like `<img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ image.imgfile.name }}"></img>`

Put imports in these groups: `future`, `standard library`, `third-party libraries`, other Django components, `local Django component`, `try/excepts`

Take a look at [django coding style](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/contributing/writing-code/coding-style/)

Foreign Key with defaults you should ensure the object is created before the migration. Take a look at 
[Setting default value for Foreign Key attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9311996/setting-default-value-for-foreign-key-attribute)

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.contrib import admin

from .models import Customer, Address

class CustomerAddressInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Address

@admin.register(Customer)
class CustomerAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ["first_name","last_name","phone_number"]
    inlines = [CustomerAddressInline]

    search_fields = ["first_name","last_name","phone_number"]
    fields = ("first_name","last_name","phone_number", "profile_image",)
```

Also Clarify your question.

Comment: I am concedering the other issues.. I said before. i have to make multiple address add option from admin view.The address has 4 fields,country,state,city,pin code.. and when admin/staff click on add more address ,a new div would show with all address fields on that customer profile. Please ignore all other issues.Please help me ,how can i manage them,if I planned something wrong.. if not ,how can I do that.