# customize save function of rest-auth registration

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

I have a user model something like this

```
class Role(models.Model):

    ROLE_CHOICES = (
        ('agent', 'Agent'),
        ('agency', 'Agency'),
        ('manufacturer', 'Manufacturer'),
    )
    role = models.CharField(max_length=15, choices=ROLE_CHOICES)

    def __str__(self):
        return 'role'


class User(AbstractUser):

    role = models.ForeignKey(
        Role,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        blank=True,
        null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)
```

The user can be of 3 types. But at the time of registration, the user should be created with the role of agent.The endpoint for the user registration is /rest-auth/registration. This will create only a normal user with username and password. But i need to create the agent role as well. I believe, it should be done in `save` method of rest-auth registration serializer but I don't know how to customize the registration serializer. Can anyone shed me the light, please?

Comment: You can try setting default value in foreign key like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9311996/setting-default-value-for-foreign-key-attribute - so when a new object gets created, a new value will be assigned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can done it several ways.

**Method 1**

Use a `callable default function` on model:

```
def get_defaul_role():
    role, created = Role.objects.get_or_create(role='agent')
    return role</b>

class User(AbstractUser):
    role = models.ForeignKey(Role, on_delete=models.CASCADE, <b>default=get_defaul_role</b>)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)
```

**Method 2**

By overriding `save()` method

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    role = models.ForeignKey(Role, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.pk: # If instance is created
            self.role, created = Role.objects.get_or_create(role='agent')
        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Reference : [Django's `get_or_create()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create)

Comment: do i still need default when overriding save() method?

Comment: No...you can use **either** `Method-1` or `Method-2`

Comment: before i did not use to get csrf issue but now I am getting csrf issue when posting data in rest-auth/registration.

Comment: Anyway, ask a new question in SO. (comment that url here, so I could give a try) or [go through similar question](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=csrf+verification+failed.+request+aborted.+DRF+site:stackoverflow.com&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiY7sTLqpncAhWJuo8KHbtvCqwQrQIoBDAAegQIAhAN&biw=1366&bih=626)

Answer (score 0):

Simply set a default value for `role`:

```
role = models.ForeignKey(
        Role,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        default=Role.objects.get(role='agent'))
```

Comment: what if there is no role object with agent. I have to add the role from the admin for this to work i think. Will not it be better, if i check in save method if role object with agent exists or not if not then create one and assign. What is your suggestion on this?

Comment: If you are going to create a `Role` of `'agent'` anyway, you can use `default=Role.objects.get_or_create(role='agent')[0]` instead.

Comment: that way I am getting "There are some values Django cannot serialize into migration files." error when doing makemigrations