# How to set the default value for ForeignKey

Tags: python, sql, django

I have this field

```
graduation_year = m.ForeignKey('GraduationYear', on_delete=m.SET_NULL, null=False,blank=False)
```

and `GraduationYear` class is.

```
class GraduationYear(BaseModel):
    label = m.CharField(max_length=255)
    year = m.CharField(max_length=255,unique=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.label
```

Now I want to set the `GraduationYear` object where year=2022 as the default value of `graduation_year`

So, I am guessing I should embed sql to here below.

```
graduation_year = m.ForeignKey('GraduationYear', on_delete=m.SET_NULL, null=False,blank=False,default='select GraduationYear where year=2022')
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting default value for Foreign Key attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9311996/setting-default-value-for-foreign-key-attribute)

Comment: I think you can assign objects to the "default" value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your table is only managed using the ORM, a good approach would be to override the `save` method on the model to set it if not provided:

```py
class GraduationYear(BaseModel):
    label = m.CharField(max_length=255)
    year = m.CharField(max_length=255,unique=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.label


class GraduationDetails(BaseModel):
    graduation_year = m.ForeignKey('GraduationYear', on_delete=m.SET_NULL, null=False, blank=False)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.graduation_year:
            self.graudation_year, _ = GraduationYear.objects.get_or_create(year=2022)
        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: It works perfect for my purpose.

Answer (score 0):

```
default=lambda: GraduationYear.objects.get_or_create(year=2022)[0]
```

Comment: Please consider adding some explanation to the source code explaining how it solves the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.I use @ybl way for this problem. I appreciate your answer.