# can i use default argument on foreignkey?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

i added a str default to foreign key but when i tried to create superuser i got error with this argument :

```
 ValueError: Field 'id' expected a number but got 'personal'.
```

heres my code :

```
class Genders(models.Model):
    get_gender = models.TextField()

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    age = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True,validators=[
        MaxValueValidator(100),MinValueValidator(6)])

    gender = models.ForeignKey(Genders,default='personal',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

can you help with this problem ? im learning django cant debug yet but i thought maybe problem is that superuser doesnt have a gender value

Comment: Is personal a value from Genders model ?

Comment: yes it is but didnt modify Gender Class thought i can do it later

Comment: Try this then `gender = models.ForeignKey(Genders,default = Genders.objects.get(get_gender='personal').id,on_delete=models.CASCADE)`

Comment: After that do not forget to run makemigrations and migrate.

Comment: I want also to add that the `get_gender`  should be just a `CharField`

Comment: Is it working now ?

Comment: just trying to add personal to query got this :'```raise self.model.DoesNotExist(
users.models.Genders.DoesNotExist: Genders matching query does not exist.```

Comment: So that means that you did not add personal in your model Genders

Comment: First add it in your database Genders

Comment: well i did try to add using shell but didnt let me

Comment: thanks for help my bad i should back and study python again first

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting default value for Foreign Key attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9311996/setting-default-value-for-foreign-key-attribute)

Comment: @ThiernoAmadouSow please don't advise people to run queries on the module level, no queries should be run before Django has initialized all apps, etc. Hence all queries need to go in functions / methods.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass `ID` not a `gender name` because `ForeignKey` needs to `ID` not a `gender name`

```py
    class Genders(models.Model):
        get_gender = models.TextField()

    class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
        age = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True,validators=[
            MaxValueValidator(100),MinValueValidator(6)])
    
        gender = models.ForeignKey(Genders,default='1',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```