# Django create an object when enter its link

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

the title probably doesn't tell my problem, sorry about it.

I have a `models.py` like this:

```
class Baslik(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

I have a function to add object to Baslik model. I just enter a title and it works fine.
This is my `forms.py`:

```
class BaslikForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Baslik
        fields = ('title',)
```

My urls for every object is like this: `url(r'^(?P<title>.*)/$', 'tek', name = "tek_baslik")`
I want to create a new object when user enter its future link if it isn't already created. For instance when user enters `/baslik/stack` I want to create a "stack" object immediately and render its page that defined in `views.py` for every object.
How can I do this. Any idea would help. Thanks.

Comment: And what kind of precautions will you use? if for instance someoone starts flooding you with random strings?

Comment: I have another model that named as Entry and connected to baslik. It has baslik as foreign key. I can define a function to remove basliks if it's not have entries in it. Also it should be available for users only and if user floods I can ban the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an approach you can take:

1) Define a new url structure:

```
url(r'^baslik/(?P<title>.*)/$', views.baslik_handle, name = "tek_baslik")
```

2) You don't need the modelform, you can directly handle it through the views. Use [get_or_create](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1941212/correct-way-to-use-get-or-create) in views.baslik_handle. e.g.

```
def baslik_handle(request, title):
   baslik, created = Baslik.objects.get_or_create(title=title)
```

Comment: The object is created only if it isn't already there.  It checks for you.

Comment: In above code, created is False if object already exists. If new object is created, created is set to True.

Answer (score 1):

The ModelForm is unnecessary, try this:

**view**

```
def create_baslik(request, title):
    context = RequestContext(request)
    context_dict = {}

    baslik, created = Baslik.objects.get_or_create(title=title, user=request.user)
    context_dict['baslik'] = baslik

    return render_to_response('baslik.html', context_dict, context)
```

**template**

```
{% if baslik %}
    {{ baslik.title }}
    ...
{% endif %}
```