# is there an easier way to either create or re-write exist object? django

Tags: python, django, object

I know in django we can create an object model easily by using something like this

`AbcModel.objects.create(field1='a', field2='b')`

But this would create the object even if it already exists.
I know I can use `filter()` then use the `exist()` to check if the object already exist then decide to update or create.

But is there an easier and faster way to do this?  Since, there is `get_or_create` so I am curious if there's something similar.

Thanks in advance

EDIT:
I thought of something like this

```
new = AbcModel.objects.create(field1='a')
new[0].field2 = 'c'
new[0].save()
```

There might be more fields and `field1` will not always be `a` would be others like `b`, `c` and maybe `a` again.

Just being curious if there is an easier faster way and not saying `get_or_create` wouldn't get what I want / need

Comment: What does `get_or_create()` not do that you want it to do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Correct way to use get\_or\_create?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1941212/correct-way-to-use-get-or-create)

Answer (score 1):

As you said about [`get_or_create`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create), you could do:

`abc_instance, created = AbcModel.objects.get_or_create(field1='a', field2='b')`

That would bring you the existent/created object as the first argument and a boolean as the second argument, that defines if it was got or created.

Additionally, `field1` and `field2` will be used for the filter, but you can set the `defaults` attribute, which will update the existing entry or be used for its creation.

```
abc_instance, created = AbcModel.objects.get_or_create(
    field1='a', field2='b',
    defaults={'field3': 'c', 'field4': 'd'}
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `update_or_create`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#update-or-create

However if the field you filter by is not unique, you might end up getting a `MultipleObjectsReturned` exception.

Another way to do this could be:

```
num_updated = AbcModel.objects.filter(field1='a').update(field2='c')
if num_updated == 0:
    model = AbcModel.objects.create(field1='a', field2='c')
```

In `num_updated` you will have the number of rows updated in the first line of code.

I hope this helps a bit!