# How to check if data already exists in the table using django

Tags: django, database

I am new with django framework struggling to compare value from the database.
this are my tables in models.py :

```
class Post(models.Model):
   user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
   title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   content = models.TextField()
   creationDate = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
   lastEditDate = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

   def __str__(self):
       return self.title

class Votes(models.Model):
   user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
   post_id = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
   up_vote = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0, validators=[MinValueValidator(0), MaxValueValidator(1)])
   down_vote = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0, validators=[MinValueValidator(0), MaxValueValidator(1)])

   class Meta:
       unique_together = (("user","post_id"),)
```

I have data in the vote tabe like this:
      [image]

Now what I want is to check in the above table if 'user_id' and 'post_id' already exists in the Votes tabel's rows if the exist throw a message if not add value on upvote or downvote, i gues everyone understand what i want if not please let me know.

something which i tried was this code:

```
def chk_table():
    user_id = request.user
    post_id = id
    votes_table = Votes.objects.filter(user_id=user_id, post_id= post_id).exists()
    return votes_table
```

but this function is checking in hole table not just in just in one row...

Comment: Your function chk_table is doing exactly what you have described. Not sure what the issue is

Comment: As a side note, you shouldn’t shorten your function names. check_table is far more readable

Comment: You can also use Django's get_or_create method from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1941246/4786985).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming that, in your `urls.py`

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import add_vote

urlpatterns = [
    path('post/<int:post_id>/vote/add/', add_vote, name='add-vote'),
]
```

In your `views.py`

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render

def add_vote(request, post_id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # receive your POST data here
        user_id = request.user.id
        post_id = post_id
        if not Votes.objects.filter(user_id=user_id, post_id=post_id).exists():
            Votes.objects.create(**your_data)
        redirect('your-desired-url')
    else:
        # your logic here
```

Comment: thanks you really appriciate that i used this method and its worked.

Answer (score 2):

I see you already defined `unique_together` in `Meta` so you can use `try except`

```
from django.db import IntegrityError

try:
    # your model create or update code here
except IntegrityError as e: 
    if 'unique constraint' in e.message:
        # duplicate detected
```

Comment: thank you for answering i used other method i am not using this because i modified the other errors.